# Revel and Docker container

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, revel

I am attempting to create a docker container that contains the revel skeleton app.  Everything seems to build OK and the container is created but when I go to localhost:9000 in my browser nothing comes up.
To make sure my environment is working properly I created a simple hello world go app and created a docker container for it.  It worked OK using the same port 9000.  This makes me think that there is something not configured properly in my dockerfile.

Dockerfile:

```
#Compile stage
FROM golang:1.11.4-alpine3.8 AS build-env
ENV CGO_ENABLED 0
RUN apk add --no-cache git
ADD . /go/src/revelapp

# Install revel framework
RUN go get -u github.com/revel/revel
RUN go get -u github.com/revel/cmd/revel
#build revel app
RUN revel build revelapp app dev

# Final stage
FROM alpine:3.8
EXPOSE 9000
WORKDIR /
COPY --from=build-env /go/app /
ENTRYPOINT /run.sh
```

Docker command used:

```
docker build -t revelapp . && docker run -p 9000:9000 --name revelapp revelapp
```

After command is executed and container is created the console shows:

```
INFO  17:25:01    app     run.go:32: Running revel server                      
INFO  17:25:01    app   plugin.go:9: Go to /@tests to run the tests.           
Revel engine is listening on.. localhost:9000
```

When I go to localhost:9000 I would expect to see the text It Works!

Comment: What happens when you try to visit the URL?

Comment: When I go to localhost:9000 chrome shows: localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: What's in the container logs, then?

Comment: it is the same as what is showing in the console, what was in the last part of my post above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're listening on `localhost:9000`, so 127.0.0.1 points to your container and not your local machine.

You have two solutions to make it work:

- Listen on `0.0.0.0:9000`
- Use --network="host" in your docker run command: 127.0.0.1 in your docker container will point to your docker host.

Comment: Where do you see port 8000? I can't find that in the question anywhere.

Comment: I'm pretty sure 8000 was a typo. The point being made is 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost, not the port.

Comment: I am using windows docker CE so the network interface is bound to my local machine.  As i said before, I tested using a simple hello world go app and same dockerfile.  Everything worked fine using localhost:9000

Comment: I was able to get it to work by setting the http.addr to 0.0.0.0 in the Revel app.conf file.